# How to combine bar chart and point chart Visual c#

Tags: c#, bar-chart

I have defined a bar chart in which I show average values in the bar (there are three measurements per bar). To show the variance of the data I would like to plot the individual data values as points on the graph. How can I assign the x values to the points graph?

```
        chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.MinorGrid.Interval = .05;
        chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.MajorGrid.Interval = .1;
        chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.MinorGrid.Enabled = true;
        chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
        chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.LabelStyle.Interval = 1;
        chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.LabelStyle.Interval = .1;
        chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.MajorTickMark.Interval = .1;
        chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.MajorTickMark.Interval = 1;
        chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX2.IsStartedFromZero = false;
        chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX2.Minimum = 0;
        chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX2.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
        chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX2.CustomLabels.Clear();
        double k = .3;
                k = k + .3;
            int ij = 0;
            {
                foreach (var series in chart1.Series)
                {
                    if (series.Name.ToString() == "Measurement")
                    {
                    }
                    else{
                    chart1.Series["Measurement"].Points.AddXY(k, nyers[ij]);
                        chart1.Series["Measurement"].Points.AddXY(k, nyers[ij + 1]);
                       chart1.Series["Measurement"].Points.AddXY(k, nyers[ij + 2]);
                    series.Points.AddXY(mr["orig_code2"], (nyers[ij] + nyers[ij + 1] + nyers[ij + 2]) / 3);
                        k=k+.1;
                        ij = ij + 3;
                    }
                }
           }
```

Comment: What is `Type` "Chart1"? What Charting package are you using?

Comment: Checkout HighChartsJS they have some nice combo charts http://www.highcharts.com/

Comment: chart1 is System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart

Comment: how do I include highcharts into my c# application?

Answer (score 0):

Add another `Series` to the same `ChartArea` and set the `ChartType` property on the other series to `Point`.

Comment: This is what I did (added another chart type point) but the problem is I cannot align the point with the bar chart. If I use the Xvalue same as the bar chart, the points are added after the bar chart.  (i am not allowed to include the picture). So I tried to estimate where the bar chart puts the bars (this is what the attached code contains) but the points are not aligned.

Comment: I don't fully understand why you iterate your `Series`-collection on the chart. I did a similar approach on a project and iterated through the collection that the chart was based on. Then on each iteration I added the point to each series.

Comment: Well, the background, if you are interested: I am comparing 12 groups of 7 measurements (each measurement is repeated 3 times). The seven measurements contain varying proportion of two drugs (one drug is always the same), and 12 drug pairs fit on a measurement plate. So I have 7 bar charts one for each proportion and a point chart which will show the variation in the measurement points.

Comment: The measurement points come from a database and they are stored by compounds, so this is why I am iterating through the series.